# Showing output of multiple tLogRow components

Tags: logging, talend

I have a job. It has two subjobs. The subjobs run in sequence. Both have tLogRow components. I am only seeing the output from the first subjob that runs. How do I view the output from both subjobs.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to view the result of multiple tLogRow in the output window. Instead you can pass the tLogRow's result to a file and check the result. Check below s/s for reference.

[image]

Thank you